# Always getting Not Reachable in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Earlier i have always used Tony Million's [Reach-ability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) and it always worked fine.Now i have also tried Apple's [Reach-ability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) but each time i try to access i always get Internet not Reachable response.

**Is there anything else i should check?**

Here is what i did

```
  Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            blockLabel.text = @"Block Says Reachable";
        });
    };

    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            blockLabel.text = @"Block Says Unreachable";
        });
    };

    [reach startNotifier];
```

Comment: try to remove www and leave just reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"]

Comment: Seems like to answer quickly isn't a good idea - I've faced with issue that "http" protocol should be removed at the beginning, BUT NOT www

Answer (score 4):

You can also use for checking Internet connection,
First you need to import in you file

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

in .h file

```
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork
{

    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

    BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags);
    CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);

    if (!didRetrieveFlags)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable;
    BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired;
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? YES : NO;
}
```

If this methods return YES then internet connection is available.

May this help you...

Answer (score 2):

if face same problem so i open Reachability.m file and commit 3g.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    if(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)
    {
       // We're on 3G.
       if(!self.reachableOnWWAN)
          {
          // We don't want to connect when on 3G.
           connectionUP = NO;//Commit this line
         }
    }
#endif
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    if(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)
    {
       // We're on 3G.
       if(!self.reachableOnWWAN)
          {
          // We don't want to connect when on 3G.
           //connectionUP = NO;
         }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: would you like to elaborate where you want this to be updated. i mean i mentioned both apple and Another reachability.

Comment: and the function name also

Comment: In Another reachability change this. No need to chnage in apple reachability. Function name is  -(BOOL)isReachableWithFlags:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags {  }

Comment: Working.. Accepted. Thanks Ayaz Bhai .. :)

Comment: A.A! Brother can you tell that why are we not considering 3G and that user wouldn't be able to use the application in case he is on 3G?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.Google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];

    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN))
    {
        blockLabel.text = @"Block Says Unreachable";
    }
    else
    {
        blockLabel.text = @"Block Says Reachable";
    }
```

Comment: Ammm. where is the Block.?

Answer (score 1):

The old Reachability files are no good. Apple has updated their reachability files.

Check here.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Download here.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Reachability.zip

Answer (score 1):

I have a same issue with the Tony Million's Reachability : network status was always set to NotReachable. I fix it with adding the SystemConfiguration Framework

Hope it helps